# Is there a name for a node that doesn't have any edges?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Consider the following graph (in graphviz)

```
graph {
  a
  b - c
  d
  e - f -g
}
```

This is a disconnected graph. One could describe this graph as a forest with 4 trees.

Is there any name for the nodes `b` and `d` that aren't connected to anything else? like `solo nodes` or `isolated nodes` or something like that?

Comment: Isolated nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as an isolated node or isolated vertex.